# How do I locate the error in a lisp file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

When working with my .emacs init file, I sometimes make a mistake. When I do eval-buffer, I get the message "end of file during parsing."

How do I ask Emacs to tell me the exact location of the error?

Comment: For *this* kind of error, the exact location is the end of file, but it's not very helpful :) Try reindenting the file and see where indentation becomes wrong.

Comment: Anton is right, those are really painful, but you usually can avoid them by using a good lisp editing mode and calling `indent-region` on the buffer. You can see where things go wrong when the indentation isn't as expected.

Comment: This error means you have mis-matched parentheses.

Comment: @pmr Thanks. So what's a good lisp editing mode?

Comment: @PeterSalazar For Emacs Lisp, the built-in mode is likely the best you can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These errors are very hard to actually locate.

Better try hard to avoid mismatching parenthesis at all.  There are several built-in and 3rd-party minor modes that help you in this:

- `electric-pair-mode`:  Insert matching closing parenthesis automatically (built-in)
- `show-paren-mode`:  When point is over a parenthesis, highlight the matching one (built-in)
- `rainbow-delimiters-mode`: Highlight each level of parenthesis in a different face
- `paredit-mode`: Keep parenthesis balanced at all time.  Generally, focus editing on Sexps instead of characters and words.

I'd recommend to enable all of these.  A reasonable configuration to defeat mismatched parenthesis is thus:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(show-paren-mode 1)
(electric-pair-mode 1)
```

Paredit and Rainbow Delimiters are available from MELPA.

Answer (score 20):

The first thing is to check the balancing of parentheses and string quotes.

For Emacs Lisp In GNU Emacs use `M-x check-parens`.

Other Emacs-like editors have similar commands. In LispWorks for example one can use `M-x Find Unbalanced Parentheses`.

Comment: Have been using Emacs for quite a long time now, and never missed this function.  This of course changed as I am now aware that it exists.

Comment: you are life saver :)